# MacOS Xcode linking

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker

How Xcode is actually linking projects, and how can I link project if it is very huge? For example, I have a source files .cpp and .h and I need to build them into project, how should I link them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xcode like any compiler uses a linker and it actually shows you the precise command it's running to link if you look in the right log window.

If you have all the files in the same target executable they'll get compiled and linked automatically.

If the project is very large it just takes longer to compile and link, but it works just the same.

Comment: okay and why we need then makefiles for linking in Xcode ?

Comment: You don't. Xcode has its own build system that's independent from `Makefile`.

Comment: Thank you a lot !